# How to delete 'empty' lines in txt file

Tags: python, python-3.x, txt

I think I've tried everything to make it work but I still can't get the results I want. I basically want to delete empty lines in txt file that my other script created. I've tried: .isspace(), deleting lines with n amount of spaces, deleting lines with '\n'. None of these worked can you guys help me? Here is part of txt file and my code:

````
Gmina Wiejska
 Urząd Gminy Brzeziny 
 

 

 ul. Sienkiewicza 16a 95-060 Brzeziny
Łącko
Gmina Wiejska
 Urząd Gminy Łącko 


Łącko 445 33-390 Łącko
Węgliniec
Gmina Miejsko-wiejska
 Urząd Gminy i Miasta Węgliniec 


ul. Sikorskiego 3 59-940 Węgliniec```
````

code:

```
delete = ['<td align="center" class="top" colspan="3"><b>',
          '</td>',
          '<br/></b></td>',
          '<br/></b>',
          'None',
          'brak',
          '[]',
          '\n'
          ]
with open('/Users/dominikgrzeskowiak/python/gminy/text/text1.txt','r+') as file:
    for line in file:
        print(a)
        for i in delete:
            line = line.replace(i,'')
            print(i)
        print(line)  
        if line != '  ' or line != ' \n' or line != '   ':  
            with open('/Users/dominikgrzeskowiak/python/gminy/text/text2.txt','a') as f:
                f.write(line+'\n')
```

Comment: Notice in the given answer that `if line.strip()`: works because an empty string "" is in Python considered to be False and a non-empty string is considered to be True. So if there is still content in the line after removing all white-spaces it would be written to the other file, else not.

Answer (score 2):

Just check if the line is not empty after removing blanks with `strip`

```
with open('text1.txt', 'r+', encoding='utf-8') as file, open('text2.txt', 'a', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    for line in file:
        if line.strip():
            f.write(line)
```

You should open `text2` once, not every line in the `text1`.

Answer (score 0):

**You could use regex for searching patterns**

```
import re


with open('somefile.txt','r') as file:
    txt = file.readlines()for i in txt:
    if re.fullmatch("\\s*",i):
        continue
    print(i,end="")
```

but you could do it with pure python too

```
with open('somefile.txt','r') as file:
     txt = file.readlines()
     for i in txt:
         if i.strip() == '':
              continue
      print(i, end='')
```